# Safe args: cannot resolve symbol 'string'

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, type-safety, android-navigation

I'm using Navigation Architecture Components, and I wanted to take advantage of the safe args plugin.

I want to add some arguments to one of my fragments in the navigation graph. The arguments code is generated via the Design editor. Here's a snippet:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/inAppPurchaseFragment"
    android:name="purchaseFragment" >
    <argument
        android:name="attribution_id"
        app:type="string" />
</fragment>
```

However, I'm getting an error in Android Studio (3.2 Canary 16) that says it cannot resolve the symbol 'string', or any type I try to use. Have any of you had this issue & do you know why it's occurring?

Update for more context; I get this error during build on the line that has `app:type="string"`:

`error: 'string' is incompatible with attribute type (attr) integer.`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, make sure you add a defaultValue to it

```
android:defaultValue="something"
```

And by the way, have you implemented `Navigation Architecture Components` as it says on [`adding-components documentation`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#navigation) ?

```
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin

    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did set it up according to the adding-components documentation. Did that work for you? Were you able to use safe args? Also, were you able to set a type that you yourself defined via `app:type`?

Comment: Yes, I followed this [tutorial](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/exploring-androids-navigation-architecture-component) days ago and it worked. Also if you want to start by 0 see this [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOpeBbfyb6s)

Comment: That's alright, I've already got a working navigation graph. I just wanted to leverage safe args to tie it all together. I suspect it has something to do with resource-inking.

Comment: @SabaImran Not getting you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha02"
```

in your project level build.gradle

and put

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

in your application level build.gradle.

.................

`android:defaultValue` is optional

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, i replaced

```
<argument
        ...
        app:type="string"
        .../>
```

to

```
<argument
        ...
        app:argType="string"
        .../>
```

and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've moved a class that I was using as an `Argument` from a package to another. To solve the problem I rewrote the right path for the class inside `app:argType`.

This issue happens because even though you click on "Refractor" when you move a class from a package to another the path inside the `app:argType` doesn't change.